# Storing info into an array of another class

Tags: java

I've been working on this for a while but can't seem to get it. I need to store user input into an array from another object but I can't  get it to work. I'm not sure if its my constructor or I'm missing something but any help is appreciated

Here is the output program

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Enter   'p' to create a polygon");
       String in = sc.next();

    if (in.equals("p")) {
        System.out.println("How many sides?");
        int numSides = sc.nextInt();
        int side=0; 

        Polygon ps;
        for (int i = 1; i <= numSides; i++) {

            System.out.println("Enter the length of side " + i);
            side = sc.nextInt();
             ps = new Polygon(side);

        }
         ps = new Polygon(side);
```

Here is the constructor of the other class

```
public class Polygon {
    protected int[] sideLengths;


public Polygon(int sides){
    sideLengths= new int[sides];

}
```

Comment: adding ps = new Polygon(side);
in the loop is useless as object for whole polygon has to be made not for each side therefore initializing ps in loop with each side logically incorrect

Comment: @codechefvaibhavkashyap thanks for the info! I was  moving everything  around to see if something magical happens ahah

Comment: tinkering with the code is nice. But whatever result comes you need to find out why it did happen. Keep going.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do

```
ps=new Polygon(numSides+1); //adding 1 because for-loop starts with index 1
for (int i = 1; i <= numSides; i++) {

      System.out.println("Enter the length of side " + i);
      side = sc.nextInt();
      ps[i]=side;

}
```

by this what we do is assign the 'side' value entered by user to a particular index in array.

hope this helps!

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand your Program I think you are looking for this kind of logic

```
if (in.equals("p")) {
            System.out.println("How many sides?");
            int numSides = sc.nextInt();
            int side = 0;

            Polygon ps;
            int sideLengths[] = new int[numSides];// array to store length of  polygon of sides `numSides`
            for (int i = 1; i <= numSides; i++) {

                System.out.println("Enter the length of side " + i);
              sideLengths[i-1] = sc.nextInt();// creating array to store lengths


            }
            ps = new Polygon(sideLengths);// generating your pollygon by sending the array

        }
```

And you Polygon class should look like this

```
    class Polygon {

            protected int[] sideLengths;// storing the lengths of all sides

            public Polygon(int dimensions[]) {
                sideLengths = dimensions ;

            }
        }
```

Comment: I am getting hard time understanding this, if someone has designed a class and is asking for a solution to a problem, how on earth can we tell him to change his code? rather than providing a solution to the original problem,because same code might have been used somewhere else and changing it might be risky?

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Enter   'p' to create a polygon");
       String in = sc.next();


            if(in.equalsIgnoreCase("p")) {
                Integer sides[];
                System.out.println("How many sides?");
                int numSides = sc.nextInt();
                int side=0; 
                if(numSides>0){
                    sides = new Integer[numSides];
                }
                Polygon ps;
                for (int i = 1; i <= numSides; i++) {

                    System.out.println("Enter the length of side " + i);
                    side = sc.nextInt();
                    sides[i] = side;

                }

                ps = new Polygon(sides);
            }
     }

public class Polygon {
    private Integer[] sides;
    public Polygon(Integer[] sides){
        this.sides = sides;
    }
}
```

Now we have created an array of size of sides and array is been passed as an argument to constructor for initializing Polygon's object

Comment: I am getting hard time understanding this, if someone has designed a class and is asking for a solution to a problem, how on earth can we tell him to change his code? rather than providing a solution to the original problem

Comment: @Vihar One shouldn't forget that once we were naive too. Either help till the other end or you shouldn't. Anyways if you've any contradictions to my solution. Suggestions are always welcome.

Comment: never meant to contradict anyone, but I think differently

Answer (score 0):

it should be like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Enter   'p' to create a polygon");
   String in = sc.next();

if (in.equals("p")) {
    System.out.println("How many sides?");
    int numSides = sc.nextInt();
    int side=0; 

    Polygon ps = new Polygon(numSides);
    for (int i = 1; i <= numSides; i++) {

        System.out.println("Enter the length of side " + i);
        side = sc.nextInt();
        ps.addSide(side, i-1);
         //ps = new Polygon(side);

    }
     //ps = new Polygon(side);
}}}
```

and Polygon class like

```
public class Polygon {
    protected int[] sideLengths;


    public Polygon(int sides){
        sideLengths= new int[sides];

    }
    public void addSide(int side, int index){
        sideLengths[index] = side;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are calling the constructor correctly, but after for loop ends you are again creating a new instance of Polygon and assigning it to ps. Either create an array of int or ArrayList of Integer, and store each instance of Polygon side length in that just before the for loop ends.

```
ArrayList<int> psListpsSideLengthList = new ArrayList<int>;
for (int i = 1; i <= numSides; i++) {

    System.out.println("Enter the length of side " + i);
    side = sc.nextInt();
     psListpsSideLengthList.add(side);

}
```